# splitting the address string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a address string. i want to show the address in the following way,

**KG Halli, D Souza Layout**

```
var add = "KG Halli, D Souza Layout, Ashok Nagar, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560001, India";
alert(add.split(',')[add.split(',').length-4]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean

```
alert(add.split(',').slice(0,-4).join(','));
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10345786)

Comment: Sorry, I was disallowed to comment posts at that moment. And there was no question at all :)

Comment: thanks Roman..this solved my problem